# "freeze" terminal output (/dev/tty1)

Tags: linux, console, freeze

I'm writing an application (in java) that directly operates on the framebuffer (/dev/fb0).

When I start my app, the cursor of the currently active console still blinks and if i use keyboard-keys like up/down the console will display the recently used commands and overwrite the framebuffer's content.

I was only able to stop the cursor from blinking:

```
setterm -cursor off > /dev/tty1
```

Is there a way to totally freeze (and later unfreeze) the console?

It seems like an X-Server does the same thing. If the boot-process runs on GraphicsCard-1 and the X-Server on GraphicsCard-2, the output on GraphicsCard-1 will stop (no blinking cursor) immediately when X starts. I guess mplayer does this, too if setting video-out to the framebuffer.

thanks for any ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the behaviour that you've observed is more of a bug than a feature.  It's down to the fact that Linux isn't properly multi-head.  What you're seeing is an effect of the X server switching its own, allocated, [virtual terminal](http://linuxjournal.com./article/2783) onto the console.  This of course — because only *one* virtual terminal can be active at a time *system-wide* — switches out the virtual terminal that was being displayed, even though it was being displayed on another display adapter entirely.

[You have to do some of what the X server is doing, and switch your own virtual terminal onto the console.](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/vt.html)

Answer (score 0):

`openvt(1)` allows you to open a program in a new virtual terminal, and `chvt(1)` allows you to switch to another virtual terminal.

Answer (score 0):

it was a little bit more tricky to get what i exactly wanted:

I have to execute (from shell) 2 commands to get the terminal quiet:

```
chvt 9
setterm -cursor > /dev/tty9
```

later one can switch back to terminal 1:

```
setterm cursor > /dev/tty9
chvt 1
```

I choose terminal number 9 but any number above 7 should be fine. These calls also work if they are executed from within the java application (as JdeBP said, only one virtual terminal system-wide). Only the setterm command requires some additional steps to pipe the output to /dev/tty9:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chvt 9");
pipe("setterm -cursor off", "/dev/tty9");

private static void pipe(String cmd, String file) {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    int i;
    while ( (i = is.read()) != -1 ) {fos.write(i);}
    p.waitFor();
    fos.close();
    is.close();
}
```

maybe the pipe() method is not optimal, but it worked for me the way it is.